# How can Evolution connect to Exchange via the OWA connector?

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

I have been trying for a while to get Evolution to connect to my Exchange account. I think the complication is the that the OWA url is https://owa[...]. 
I am able to connect with Android phones, iPhones, etc., but I can't do it with Evolution.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: What version of Exchange server is this? <= 2003 or > 2003?

Comment: Exchange Server 2003

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/6916/exchange-with-evolution-or-any-other-mail-client

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use the `evolution-mapi` plugin - It took me a good long while to get it setup properly with my machine at work. I was able to get calendar and mail to sync properly. Some interesting things I had to do:

- For `server` I had to use the IP address of the Exchange server
- I had to use the Exchange MAPI as server type, if you're using Exchange 2003 or lower the `Microsoft Exchange` plugin will work fine.

Comment: Useing the IP address rather than the URL did not work, Still gives:
Could not configure Exchange account because 
an unknown error occurred. Check the URL, 
username, and password, and try again.

Comment: OK so I had a look at the evolution MAPI plugin, The requires direct access to the exchange server, not access to the Outlook Web Access (owa) service. I dont have access to this from this machine, only the owa service.

Comment: I'm confused - doesn't OWA typically run on the Exchange server - if I'm correct in that assumption you should be able to use that IP address, Domain (Networking Domain), and User/Pass to connect.

Comment: Also - if this is Exchange server 2003 don't use the MAPI plugin, the Microsoft Exchange option in Evolution should suite your needs (and work with OWA if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 6):

I've also failed to configure Evolution with an Exchange server (2007, I think).

DavMail came ot the rescue! http://davmail.sourceforge.net/

DavMail is a gateway that interfaces with an Exchange server and provides Evolutions with standard IMAP, Pop, CalDav etc interfaces.

Hope it helps
/N

Comment: +1 for davmail. It is the best solution for anyone with just owa access.

Comment: Can you point me to setup instructions for DavMail with Thunderbird or Evolution. I installed DavMail, but I cannot get it to actually check my mailbox nor send mail and their instructions are partially in French.

Answer (score 1):

You should normally access your 2003 Exchange through the OWA, but beware, Evolution in Maverick is critically bugged regarding the Exchange connexion. There's an open bug on the Launchpad about it : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evolution-exchange/+bug/606822

Comment: There is an update coming to correct that bug I'm talking about. To this hour, it is in the Proposed repos, I would suggest to be patient and wait for the actual update though, it should come shortly.