#  ms exchange 2007 client in ubuntu 10.04 

Tags: evolution, email, ms-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exchange with Evolution or any other mail client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6916/exchange-with-evolution-or-any-other-mail-client)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 with default **evolution**n client.i am able to configure evolution and work with ms exchange 2007,i am not happy with evolution.

So  i am looking for some other client please recommend me the best one.

Please waiting for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having worked with several solutions over the years, I found out that the unfortunate truth is that there is currently no solution on Linux that can match the features, speed, stability and ease of use of Outlook. And frankly, I'm pretty pissed because of this, especially since none of the available clients even supports open source Exchange alternatives properly (with MAPI support).

Yes, you have alternatives. You could use Thunderbird for email, Sunbird for calendaring and then some other solution for shared contacts etc, but that probably won't help you connecting to Exchange.

Outlook WebAccess won't help you much either, since Exchange 2007 will severely reduce the functionality if you're not using Internet Explorer.

If you have any influence on the back end (server side), I highly recommend evaluating alternatives like SOGO, Zimbra or Zarafa. The latter provides a WebAccess very similar to that of Exchange, but it also works perfectly on Firefox. I use it on a daily basis for all my work.

Of course if you don't have any influence on the server side, you're pretty much screwed. The only alternative I can think of in that case is running Outlook on a virtual machine or by using Wine. But I'm not sure if there are any Outlook versions that will work reliably on Wine...

If you want to know more on Exchange alternatives I can help you, but I must warn you that I have the most experience with just one of the alternatives ;-)

Comment: Thanks for reply.i also think in same way,but zimbra is the best.

Comment: This is a sad reality. I had no option but put multiboot. I hope TB will one day support Exchange!

Comment: Well... TB supporting Exchange will be quite hard, since Microsoft's MAPI implementation is proprietary. On the other hand, Zarafa's implementation of MAPI is fully open source, uses open standards and is completely documented. I'm hoping someday TB will support Zarafa, since that would be much easier to do (and then you'll have a completely free, fully capable Exchange replacement!) :-)