# How/Can I use OUTLOOK in Ubuntu Mail Server? Thanks

Tags: email, mail-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exchange with Evolution or any other mail client](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6916/exchange-with-evolution-or-any-other-mail-client)

How/Can I use OUTLOOK in Ubuntu Mail Server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a mail server first, then you can just add a new account in outlook to connect to it.
http://www.iredmail.org/install_iredmail_on_ubuntu.html

Comment: Hi Yarre. is Iredmail free?? because im gonna use it in our company with more than 200+ users

Comment: Then your company should definitely be paying/donating. From the website: "What iRedMail is... **A ZERO COST**, fully fledged, full-featured mail server solution." A Pro service/product is also available: http://www.iredmail.org/admin_buy.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Outlook come with MS Office, you could try to emulate it in wine(Don't know if it will actually work).

But I suggest you to try [Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/).