# Exchange 2010 Client for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ms-exchange

Is there a way I can check my MS Exchange email accounts in a desktop client rather than the web interface(s)? Between school, work, and personal, I have four accounts and it would be much easier to be able to check all in one place like I can with MS Outlook. I've seen ways to do this in 12.04 and some earlier but these didn't seem to work on 12.10. Any help with doing this on Ubuntu 13.04 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend seeing this question for additional options: http://askubuntu.com/q/6916/18665

Answer (score 7):

In 12.10 I used thunderbird initially, but then moved to evolution as I found the GUI much more productively designed, esp as I use OUtlook at work.

There is the `evolution-ews` package which allows you using the Exchange web services (EWS) directly to help you better integrate the client with the server. BUt I was unable to set it up correctly with Exchange 365 server I use. It may be possible to do so as I didn't have much time to research back then. But then the IMAP+ services worked well for the emails.

Comment: Also, If you really really like outlook, just install windows on a virtual machine using virtualbox. Then you can actually install outlook on the windows PC.

Answer (score 3):

Thunderbird works fine as an Exchange 2010 Client. You might need DavMail as well. Here is one way to configure it. This should work in Ubuntu 13.04 also.

http://guzaho.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/thunderbird-as-client-for-microsoft-exchange-2010-server/

Answer (score 1):

I know the last answer is some time ago, but with the package `evolution-mapi` (in the universe repository) for evolution you get a nearly fully functional outlook replacement.